# Is there a simple way to set all python method atttributes to `self.`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a function that defines many parameters in my class object - such as:

```
class Project:
    def newTask(self, taskName=None, taskDuration=None):
        self.taskName=taskName
        self.taskDuration=taskDuration
```

Is there a "natural" way of setting all (or some) of the method's parameters to `self.` attributes of the same name(s)?

---

By extension, is there is an equivalent for passing a `Task` **object** so that `Project` can `self.` the task's methods as well?

```
class Task:        
    def populate(self, taskName=None, taskDuration=None):
        self.taskName=taskName
        self.taskDuration=taskDuration

t=Task()
t.populate(taskName='Task1',taskDuration=100)

class Project:
    def newTask(self, t):
        self.taskName=t.taskName
        self.taskDuration=t.taskDuration
        self.populate
```

Comment: Couldn't you pass a `Task` object to `Project` and then in `Project` do `self.task = my_task`? Then you would access the task methods with `my_proj.task.populate(*args)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always:

```
for arg in ('taskName', 'taskDuration'):
    setattr(self, arg, locals()[arg])
```

But it's a terrible idea for readability and for automatic static code analysis. Neither me, not the computer can quickly figure out how `taskName` is used.

If you have things that belong together and are often passed around, maybe you should try `namedtuple` instead? It saves you some boilerplate code, does immutability by default, and you can pass it around as one object instead of multiple ones.

Usage would be something like:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Task = namedtuple('Task', ['name', 'duration'])

class Project:
    def addTask(self, task):
        self.tasks.append(task)

t = Task('some name', 10)
project.addTask(t)
```

Comment: Thank you very much - just to check - this can't be extended to a `Task` object with methods I take it? I'm not having much luck

Comment: @Bendy It sure can. See the end of documentation in https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple for an example. `class Point(namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])):`

Answer (score 2):

The following uses the built-in [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
def newTask(self, **kwargs):
    for name, vaue in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, name, value)
```

You might want to add validation as to whether all the kwargs you want are there.